# How to match a JS regexp that may or may not have a suffix

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to make a JS regex that returns `example` in all of these input strings, which may have question marks in them.

- `example?after?after`
- `example?after`
- `example?`
- `example`

`example` would be a dynamic string so I can't literally match the string 'example'.

```
'example?after?after'.match(/(.*?)\?/)[1]
'example?after'.match(/(.*?)\?/)[1]
'example?'.match(/(.*?)\?/)[1]
'example'.match(/(.*?)\?/)[1]
```

The first 3 above return `example` as expected but the last one gives an error. How can I modify the regex to return the expected result?

Comment: So, do you want to return everything before a question mark but if there is no question mark, return the entire string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
/^[^?]+/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3EK2C1/1)

The `^`  matches the start of string and `[^?]+` matches one or more symbols other than `?`.

```js
var regex = /^[^?]+/;
var strs =[ 'example?after?after', 'example?after', 'example?', 'example'];
for (var s of strs) 
 {
   console.log(s + " => " + s.match(regex));
 }
```

Comment: FYI, `[^?]` is an example of an *negated character class*. See more information on  [**negated character classes**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) here.

Comment: Well, a non-regex approach can be [`s.substring(0, (m=s.indexOf('?')) > -1 ? m : s.length)`](https://jsfiddle.net/juas2u3r/).

Comment: Is there any problem with skipping the first `^`? The results are the same without it in these examples.

Comment: By "skipping" you mean "omitting"/"discarding"? Well, it is a verbose way to tell the regex engine to only check the pattern at the start of the string. If there is a `?` at the start of the string, this `/^[^?]+/` regex will not match. If you remove the `^`, it will find a match later (if the string is not just a `?`).